# how to hide label name in polybar + bspwm?

Tags: linux, window-manager

[image: workspace]

I have some problems with polybar/bspwm module
If i get notification in any workspace, it show label name

How to hide label name?
[my bspwm module config](https://pastebin.com/0ay6eUbr)

[image: workspace2]

Comment: It would be best to copy the config into the question inside a code block. Paste in the information from the config file, select it, then push the button that looks like {}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [bspwm module](https://github.com/polybar/polybar/wiki/Module:-bspwm) has a separate label that is used if bspwm marks a workspace as urgent; it is called `label-urgent`.

Your config does not specify a value for this label so it uses its default value which is `label-urgent = %icon% %name%`. You need to specify a value for it, just as you did for `label-focused`, `label-empty`, etc., to make it consistent.

Comment: Awesome, thanks a lot!